# How to diagnose NGINX/PHP slowness

Tags: php, nginx, diagnostics

Developing NGINX/PHP web site.  Significant discrepancy between NGINX and PHP processing times and I don't know how to diagnose.

Pulling a JPEG from the NGINX server is speedy.

```
ab -l -c 100 -n 10000 http://blah.com/a_40kb_file.jpg
```

7,700 Requests per second. NGINX log says served between 2ms and 8ms.

Pulling a PHP front page is another matter.  It's a simple form with no graphics so each connection represents a page.  Each download is approx 3kb.  Each page is different as it contains a randomised token in the form.

```
ab -l -c 100 -n 10000 http://blah.com/
```

900 requests per second.  NGINX log says served between 15ms and 250ms.  No errors reported from NGINX.  PHP-FPM complained about reaching max pm.max_children.  Increased until no more error.

The PHP script records execution time by simple `microtime(true)` at the beginning and end.  These are showing that:

Calling a single page, the NGINX log time and the PHP rune time broadly align (approx 1 to 2 ms).

Under simulated load, the NGINX time goes mad but the PHP execution time remains the same.

NGINX is waiting around somewhere for something to happen and I don't know how to diagnose.  Are any tools/methods available?

```
NGINX.CONF
worker_processes auto;
worker_connections 768;
```

Dev platform:
1 Core VM. Vbox 6.0. Guest: Ubuntu 18.04. Intel i5-6260U.

Comment: seem like good not realy slow for response time

Comment: I want to understand why the PHP script thinks that it is taking 1-2ms to run but NGINX takes 15-250ms to run the script.
If those figures are correct, there's some additional performance available waiting to be discovered there.